# Youtube api + webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube-api

I am trying to implement an android browser in my app that handles youtube videos.
For a couple of days I searched all over stackoverflow and google but found no answer.
So far I got a developer key for youtube api and same samples but I can't figure out how to implement it in my webview.

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The terms of service for YouTube:

http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

seem to indicate that what you trying to do is not really OK. I can think of many ways in which this will be difficult. Google/YouTube want your users to see their adverts. If you embed the player in a web site that has advertising there are terms for that too.

The correct way to do this would be to launch the YouTube link/url and have Android catch this and as they user if they want to open it using the Android YouTube app or continue to the webpage (YouTube).

Comment: That's what I am looking forward to do , I don't have my website on my application , there are different websites that randomly have youtube video in the website and I want to play it , on click , open youtube app. Thank you for your answer and for clearing stuff out.